# How can I see all method called by a method in a Eclipse, and all their called methods

Tags: eclipse, methods, ide

In Eclipse, I know how to find all the method that call my method - with the call hierarchy.
Question:  Is there a way to do the reverse?

```
The method A calls method B, C and D
method B calls C, E, F
method C calls X, Y and Z
method D calls X, F and Z
etc ....
```

Is there a way to get that tree view in eclipse, somehow?
Or is there any other tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Call Hierarchy" view of Eclipse can show trees of both directions:

- Show **caller** hierarchy (all methods **calling** a method)

  [image: 1]
- Show **callee** hierarchy (all methods **called by** a method)

  [image: 2]

Comment: Thank you.  Perfect !!  Almost what I need.  (It shows all the methods, all multiple times, i will just have to filter)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a breakpoint in the method you want the calls for and look at the callstack in the debugger when you hit that breakpoint. This is probably not as good as @Thomas Fritsch's answer but it will yield some information and works in many debuggers.